# How to make two div’s stand side by side

Tags: html, css

I have this html

```
                        <div class="portlet-header" style="width: 447px">
                            <h3>Total Calls Statuses</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div id="vertical-chart-total-calls-statuses" class="chart-holder">
                            <canvas class="overlay" width="478" height="300"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="portlet" style="background-color:green; float:right; ">
                        <div class="portlet-header" style="width: 447px">
                            <h3>Inbound</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div id="vertical-chart" class="chart-holder">
                            <canvas class="overlay" width="478" height="300"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I don't have any CSS, but I do have HTML. Here is the current result of my code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFEO3.png
I need the green div to be side by side with the red one, how do I do this?
Here’s a JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Tn58S/

Comment: Set `float: left;` to both divs.

Comment: `I don't have css classes` - what does this mean?

Comment: I'd think it means he isn't using CSS classes...

Comment: There are clearly classes in his code though

Comment: @3rror404 I mean there are no css files. I put the classes in my html just as names

Comment: @MrHunter yes exacctly just names just names

Comment: @mdesdev they becomes above each other when I followed your comment

Comment: @3rror404 anyhelp is appreciated please

Comment: Your code doesn't produce the output shown in your image http://jsfiddle.net/C68CP/ Where are the other styles coming from?

Comment: @3rror404 I will give you a working example

Comment: @3rror404 this is my code http://jsfiddle.net/Tn58S/

Comment: @3rror404 could you help please

Comment: Your example works fine as long as the screen is wide enough. I'm not sure what the problem is. If you want to use fixed widths then this is what you have to live with. Otherwise use percentages like @SteveWellens suggests below

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Tn58S/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all the content within a container DIV with a width sufficient to hold both portlet DIVs, i.e. with a width of 956px as each of your portlet DIVS contains a CANVAS with a width of 478px. So:

```
<div style="width: 956px"><!-- your content here --></div>
```

See this [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/F2Yqx/)

After checking the full code provided in your jsfiddle, I recommend the following changes:

- chartsclass needs to be wide enough to contain its content, which is 958px. So add a max-width of 958px to this class.
- As you have also set chartsclass to a width of 80%, this means that the width of contentArea, which contains chartsclass and informationClass, needs to be a minimum of 1198px, as 958 is 80% of 1198.
- As informationClass is set to 20%, it needs to be set to a maximum width of 240px.
- As the logoArea needs to be a width of 100%, remove the float: left so that it remains as a block level element.

I've updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tn58S/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
<div class="portlet" style="background-color:green; float:right; ">
```

to

```
<div class="portlet" style="background-color:green; float:left; ">
```

and make sure to resize the window to make room for both divs.

Comment: folling your answer, the red becomes at the right and green becomes at the left but still above the green there is the yello space

Comment: I guess you need to collapse the `chart-holder` divs. You can do that by adding `visibility: collapse`.

Comment: kindly an example please

Comment: could you help please,

Comment: I have to ask a counter question: where are the two yellow divs supposed to go?

Answer (score 0):

Set the widths of the main divs to be 50%

http://jsfiddle.net/yaHwj/

`width:50`%